# Unable to send to unresolved email addresses although configured in settings

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to send an email in a workflow from a hard coded email address and I have made sure that the option is set to allow this in system settings but I still cant get it work.

Have I missed another setting? Or does this option only allow unresolved emails in the "To" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shouldnt have thought that would work from a hardcoded email address.

Crm doesnt send emails itself, it either uses the users outlook, or uses email router - both of which requrie a system user record.

In the case of the outlook it is really sent by the user, in the case of the email router it is generally sent from exchange.

Crm cant just pretend to be an email address.

Answer (score 0):

The CRM usually takes 10-12 hours to send email to un-resolved email addresses after the setting has been turned on. 
Maybe waiting helps